# Routing kohana - strange action

Tags: php, kohana

I have strange problem with Kohana. On my localhost everything works good, but on my sever I have 404 error.

It's my route:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'dashboard',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

It's my structure:

```
application/classes/Controller/admin/dashboard.php
```

That's my dashboard controller class:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Admin_Dashboard extends Controller_Admin {

    public function action_index()
    {

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to rename the admin directory to Admin and the dashboard.php file to Dashboard. If your server is a linux, case sensitivity!

Htaccess working? Are you installed and enabled the rewrite module? (Apache)